Barney Fife: "In life there are many roads..." quote?
One of our most beloved TV characters is the Incredible Barney Fife, from the Andy Griffith Show.  In one episode, I remember Barney giving Gomer a monologue that included "In life there are many roads" towards or at the beginning.
Can anyone tell me what episode that was, and also complete the transcript of that scene for me?

Have you searched YouTube? Generally, we don't do media searches for people. If you're trying to ID the exact episode, we may be able to help with that...

Anyway, searching your version of the quote plus Andy Griffith gave me this: "during our lifetime we travel many roads some big roads some little roads rocky roads and smooth roads dirt highways and improved highways". I'm not sure it's correct or what you're looking for.

@Catija Well, this technically is an episode ID question. I'll add the tag

@Walt But he's not asking for the episode name or number... just looking for a transcript or clip from the scene... He just wants the monologue.

Well, the end result is the same, though.

Yes @Catija, I spent 2 hours looking for it.

It's from A Date for Gomer (season 4, episode 9) that aired in 1963, where Barney tries to give Gomer some advice about dating:

Barney: What Andy's trying to say, Gomer, is: During our lifetime, we travel many roads. There are big roads and little roads, rocky roads and smooth roads. Dirt highways and improved roads. Now, let's take you and that new outfit you got yourself there.
Gomer: I'm going down a road.

You can see it here around 12:00:



This actually came up in a later episode (The Song Festers), when Andy had to break it to Barney that Gomer is going to sing a solo at a concert instead of Barney:

Andy: You remember a few months ago, you's talking about how life is kinda like a road, and sometimes there are smooth places where the going's nice and easy, and other times there are places where you might run into a rut or a detour or a washed out bridge?
Barney: Yeah, I remember saying that. Philosophical meanderings, you call that. Lot of truth to it, though. 


THANK YOU!!!  I was able to find The Song Festers, but I couldn't find this one.

@Catija Thanks for the timestamp. I often struggle with it here for some reason.

Actually, I didn't think it was possible to do... I was testing it based on a Meta.SE question and it ended up working. Link is in the edit history.
